# Dividing screen into two parts for iphone box2d game application

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

The concept is like i have 10 balls and one by one ball should come in between so i can do some action on it and remaining balls it should show at bottom. But I can not divide my screen into two parts to get the balls at bottom. I basically want to show all remaining balls at bottom where it should not collide or anything it will be just a display.

I have CCColorLayer extended class which I'm using to create game.

Can anyone please help me with it?

Thank you,

Ankita

Comment: Perhaps add a mockup image of what you're imagining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be simple to do since Box2d won't touch any Cocos2d elements unless you manually create a connection between a Cocos2d element and Box2d element. Among the most common is to connect a CCSprite to a b2Body by updating the sprite's position to follow the body's position after Box2d finished simulating the world after each time step.

So for your case, you can just leave the balls at the bottom as sprites only, meaning don't assign a b2Body to it yet. Other b2Body will just ignore the bottom balls. Then when it's time for the ball to enter the game stage, assign a b2Body to it and connect the sprite and body together, and voila the balls will start having collisions!

That's all I can answer based on what you wrote in the question. If you need more details, perhaps you should ad a mock-up like HanClinto commented, or post up your codes here.